# Matlab. Repeat input command to populate an Empty array index input

Tags: arrays, matlab, validation, input, indexing

These are the requirements I am assigned to do

Next, show the user a text box to specify the x axis label, and another text box to specify the y axis label.
If the user does not enter anything in the text boxes, the program should use the default labels for the x and y axes. I have this so far
x_Axis=[0,0,0];
y_Axis=[0,0,0];
x_Axis_Bnd=["start value for x Axis:" "end value for x Axis:" "increment value for x Axis:"];

```
 for i=1:1:3
    fprintf("Type in %s ",x_Axis_Bnd(i)); 
    x_Axis(i)=input(" \n");
 end
```

Here is my error i get when i press enter with no input

```
 Unable to perform assignment because the left and right
 sides have a different number of elements.

 Error in Question_1 (line 35)
   x_Axis(i)=input(" \n");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that Matlab tries to store your input string into a normal array, which is not possible. However, you can allocate `x_Axis` as string array first:

```
x_Axis = strings(1,3);
for i=1:1:3
    fprintf("Type in %s ",x_Axis_Bnd(i)); 
    x_Axis(i) = input(" \n");
end
```